# Configuring the emulation mode of an Internet Explorer WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using a webbrowser control in a C# forms application.

Here is the resource that I use to set the emulation when using Windows 8.1: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl

I now have Windows 10, and would like to know if the above link will work correctly with Windows 10's Internet Explorer? If not, what do I need to do? I do not want to corrupt any of the registry settings, and as such, I thought that I would ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Try it and find out.  You have all the tools you need to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It will work as before in Windows 10, since Windows 10 comes with IE 11.

Remember that for a 32-bit application on 64-bit OS, you'll need to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE(or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION instead.

Comment: I am coding in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with a 64-bit OS, do I need to worry about the different key if a user uses a 32-bit OS when using my application?

Comment: @user3736648 I think that you will need to account for both of them. You might want to check to make sure.